# Fastest way to get BoundingBox in a list of Points which is converted into a float array

Tags: c#

I have a very very long list of Points (up to 10,000,000), which is then transformed into List for faster performance.

The structure goes like this {p1_x,p1_y,p1_z,p2_x,p2_y,p2_z,p3_x,p3_y,p3_z...etc}

I need to find the BoundingBox for all these points in the fastest way possible:

This is how I did it:

```
            var xList = new List<float>();
            var yList = new List<float>();
            var zList = new List<float>();

            for (int i = 0; i < Vertices.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i%3==0) //X
                {
                    xList.Add(Vertices[i]);
                }
                else if(i % 3 == 1) // Y
                {
                    yList.Add(Vertices[i]);
                }
                else if (i % 3 == 2) // Z
                {
                    zList.Add(Vertices[i]);
                }
            }
            var xMax = xList.Max();
            var yMax = yList.Max();
            var zMax = zList.Max();
            var xMin = xList.Min();
            var yMin = yList.Min();
            var zMin = zList.Min();
```

Every ms in this process matters because it is being run alongside with the application everytime the viewport updates.
May I know if this process is the fastest possible way already?

Comment: instead of creating and populating the lists and then iterating them with Max/Min for a total of 6 iterations + 1 iteration of Vertices, you should try to create min/max variables instead of lists, and just check whether the current value that was supposed to go into, say, `xList`, is lower than last known minimum, or higher than the last known maximum. this will save 6 iterations at the end of your code. could be possible to do it faster tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much what @pneuma said, plus you can do much better than having to check the modulo each time too:

```
        float
            xMax = float.MinValue,
            xMin = float.MaxValue,
            yMax = float.MinValue,
            yMin = float.MaxValue,
            zMax = float.MinValue,
            zMin = float.MaxValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < Vertices.Length; i += 3)
        {
            xMax = Math.Max(xMax, Vertices[i]);
            xMin = Math.Min(xMin, Vertices[i]);
            yMax = Math.Max(yMax, Vertices[i+1]);
            yMin = Math.Min(yMin, Vertices[i+1]);
            zMax = Math.Max(zMax, Vertices[i+2]);
            zMin = Math.Min(zMin, Vertices[i+2]);
        }
```

Performance-wise this will be an improvement, albeit probably not dramatic. You're saving yourself the unnecessary overhead of building those three lists, which consumes RAM (up to 40MB it sounds like, since `float`s are 32-bit) as well as time. Aside from that (pretend you had those 3 arrays already sorted out), this will do at least as well as the 6 `.Max()`/`.Min()` calls since those are basically doing the exact same thing we are here, just for one variable at a time.

Unless you know something about the order of the points in that initial list that could help you narrow down the search, assuming they're randomly distributed I can't think of anything more efficient in C# alone (maybe shaders and a GPU could do it faster?) but happy to be proven wrong!

Comment: That's a great answer! Thanks! Very efficient as well!